# someone "lone" - attributive adjective

Tags: word-usage

The dictionary says "lone" is used only before a noun.

Can I say "there is someone lone"?
Like someone cool, someone new...

Comment: That isn't 'before a noun', is it?

Comment: @KateBunting That's an intriguing question.

Comment: I would call it a perfectly simple one.  'After a pronoun' is not 'before a noun', so it's obviously incorrect.

Comment: To improve this question, please explain why you doubt the dictionary in this case.  "lone" doesn't mean "cool, new" it means "solitary".  It is used attributively "A lone man walked down the street".  and as the dictionary says it isn't used otherwise "*He is lone" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*lone* should be used [**before** a noun](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lone+_NOUN_%2C_NOUN_+lone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).   The graphs show some usages of *lone* as a post-modifier, but it is very much less common.  I do not have the details, but [*someone lone* is not part of the listed usages](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=someone+cool%2Csomeone+new%2Csomeone+lone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).